# rebuild content of a Div tag in complete function of $.ajaxt

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I have a 4 column table of products in template,each item in table has an anchor with `onclick` like this:

```
<div id="tablepro">
    <table>
        <tr>
        {% for product in cat.products.all %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><center><a href="#" onclick="remove({{product.pk}});">delete</a></br><img style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="magnify" src="{{product.image.url}}" /></center></td>
            {% else %}
                    <td><center><a href="#" onclick="remove({{product.pk}});">delete</a></br><img style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="magnify" src="{{product.image.url}}" /></center></td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

in `remove function` I have :

```
function remove(id)
{
    var URL='{% url CompanyHub.views.catDetails company.webSite,cat.id %}';
    URL+='delpro/'+id+'/';
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        type:'POST',
        complete:function(){
            var str='<table><tr>';
            {% for product in cat.products.all %}
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    str+='</tr><tr>';
                    str+='<td><center><a href="#" onclick="remove({{product.pk}});">delete</a></br><img style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="magnify" src="{{product.image.url}}" /></center></td>';
                {% else %}
                    str+='<td><center><a href="#" onclick="remove({{product.pk}});">delete</a></br><img style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="magnify" src="{{product.image.url}}" /></center></td>';
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            str+='</table>';
            $('#tablepro').html(str);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

in `views.py` :

```
def deleteProduct(request,key,cat_id,pro_id):
    try:
        company=Company.objects.get(webSite__iexact=key)
    except Company.DoesNotExist:
        Http404
    cat=Category.objects.get(pk=cat_id)
    if pro_id:
        try:
            product=Product.objects.get(pk=pro_id)
            product.delete()
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            Http404
    return render_to_response('CompanyHub/Company/%s/cat_details.html'%(company.theme),{'company':company,'cat':cat}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

as U see I've returned `cat object` that now a `product object` has removed from its list,but I can't get my Div updated in template!that sounds like `cat object` has not been updated in template tag.

any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template are compiled on server side and the browser renders the HTML.

To update your div after ajax call, you'd need to update it using javascript code in `complete` method. Your server side view can return JSON, XML, HTML or any other data type and your `complete` method has to render that data. Here is an example of how your `complete` method should look like if your server side returns partial html (i.e. just the table):

```
complete:function(data) {
        $('#tablepro').html(data);
},
```

Comment: tnx,Now I'm trying tu build the same string in view and return it with this : return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(str), mimetype='application/html') ,but I don't know how to do this in views.py , for example I have this in str in template : src="{{product.image.url}}  , But what should I do in views.py?

Comment: Just make another template and return it as HttpResponse

Comment: I do the same but that sounds like {{product.image.url}} or {{product.name}} are not being rendered!would U mind give me more direction?

Comment: I built the string and returned it to complete function using simplejson,tnx

Answer (score 1):

Remember that templates are compiled on the server side and the resulting HTML is then passed to the client. This means that the template code you have within your `complete` function (in the ajax call) will always be the same - in other words, every time you delete an element (and `remove` is called), you are redisplaying all the original categories again, as the HTML generated within the `for` loop is created on the server side once - not asynchronously